# hair are thick at the end of it

Tags: particles, hair, system

I have been following a tutorial about a new hair system in 3.5 which I recently mentioned similar question but now I am trying to make the hair kind think at the end of the hair , I am trying hard to find what is causing it , this is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCQN5vNgHiI&t=1161s&ab_channel=BlenderStudio at 19:21 you can see the hair is thin and other , but on my picture you can see it kind thick , what Did do wrong here ? thanks [image]

[image]

Comment: First of all it would help if you plugged the _Principled Hair BSDF_ into the _Material Output_ instead of the _Color Mix_ node. And for everything else I don't have enough time right now to go through all the steps of the video o see where you might have set a value different than shown in the tutorial...

Comment: I've just watched the beginning of the tutorial now, and from 3:46 on, in the chapter "Initial Modifiers" it is explained how the shape is changed.

Comment: thank you gordon for your time mate , yeah sometimes when you are focusing on too many things , you just miss some important part , much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tips of the hair are thick because you have set the *Shape* value of the *Set Hair Curve Profile* to a negative value. The value has a range of -1 to 1 and works like this:

- `-1` = thin root, thick tip
- `0` = equal thickness of root and tip
- `+1` = thick root, thin tip

If you disable all other modifiers and increase the *Radius*, you can see the effect better:

[image: hair profile settings]

To fix your problem, just set the *Shape* value to `+0.787`.

Comment: you are a life saver my guy , much respect